# Selecionar primeiro e último dia do mês anterior

Tags: mysql, sql

Possuo a seguinte *query*:

```
select  
ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), 1) primeiro_dia, 
last_day(sysdate()) ultimo_dia
```

Que me retorna o primeiro e o último dia do mês atual de acordo com a data do sistema. Como poderia retornar o primeiro e o último dia do mês anterior de acordo com a data do sistema também?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considerando a consulta que você já tem, basta buscar os mesmos dados subtraindo da data um mês:

```
select
   ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), 1) primeiro_dia, 
   last_day(sysdate()) ultimo_dia,
   ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(SUBDATE(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), 1) primeiro_dia_mes_passado, 
   last_day(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) ultimo_dia_mes_passado
```

Comment: Ta dando erro na hora de executar teu SQL @rLinhares

Comment: @R.Santos qual o erro?

Comment: `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')), 1) primeiro_dia_mes_passado,  last_day(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)' at line 4`

Comment: tinha um parênteses a mais, agora está ok.

Comment: Ah fechou todas, já marco como correta :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY) primeiro_dia_mes_anterior,
   (LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) ultimo_dia_mes_anterior
```